laravel error: curl_setopt(): Unable to create temporary file
I am trying to create a laravel project, but this error is popping out:
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./firstProject"

In CurlDownloader.php line 197:

  curl_setopt(): Unable to create temporary file.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]

After I did a search on the curl_setopt() I understood what its function is, but I still didn't figure out how to fix the problem.
I need help please.
Thank you for your time.

the error is related to the system temporary folder. did you change things in your php.ini? what is the value for sys_temp_dir in php.ini ?

Check if your disk is full (it happens more often than anyone likes to admit)

@apokryfos hello, thank you for your comment, actually my disk ain't full

This error usually occurs when PHP can't create a temporary file for cURL due to permission issues or misconfigured temporary directory settings.
Here’s how you can fix it:

Check Directory Permissions: Ensure the directory used for temporary files (like /tmp on Linux) has the correct write permissions for the user running PHP.
Set a Custom Temp Directory: In your Laravel app, add this to your cURL options:



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TEMPFILE, '/path/to/writable/temp');



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TEMPFILE, '/path/to/writable/temp');

Verify php.ini Settings: Check the sys_temp_dir directive in php.ini and confirm it's pointing to a writable directory.

I found the problem. I didn't have the variable TMP in the environment variables.
